# Get available product's vendor from collection all vendors

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to get vendors from `collection.all_vendors` but it returns all vendors from the collection even if its not available in a sales channel. I want to get available product's vendor from collection. Any solution to be appreciatable

Comment: One option would be to create your own list via looping available collection products and picking unique vendors from each product. You might need to use pagination if you have more than 50 products per collection

Comment: Thank you @mizurnix, but it's time consuming while looping 2000 products